# Derivative of $f(x) \cdot g(x)^{(n)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}(-1)^k \cdot {n \choose k}\cdot (f(x)^{(k)}\cdot g(x))^{(n-k)}$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

can someone please help me with this rule:

$$
f(x) \cdot g(x)^{(n)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \cdot {n \choose k}\cdot (f(x)^{(k)}\cdot g(x))^{(n-k)}
$$

or you can write:

$$
f(x) \cdot \frac{d^n g(x)}{dx^n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \cdot {n \choose k}\frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}}(f(x)^{(k)}\cdot g(x))
$$

Where the powers with $()$ are derivations of the function.

Where does it come from and how can I proof it? I tried mathematical induction without success.

Thank You!

Comment: $(f(x) \cdot g(x))^{(n)}\neq f(x) \cdot g(x)^{(n)}$

Comment: Is the $\;(n)\;$ in the left side on $\;g\;$ alone or on the product? And if it is on the product, where did you take the $\;(-1)^k\;$ in the right hand side from?

Comment: The (n) in the left side is on g(x) alone and NOT on the product.

Comment: Then you need no formula at all: differentiate $\;g(x)\;\;n\;$  times and multiply by $\;f\;$ ...

Comment: For example: you're saying that

$$fg''=(fg)''-(f'g)'+(f''g)=\left(f'g+fg'\right)'-f''g-f'g'+f''g=$$

$$=f''g+\color{red}{f'g'}+f'g'+{fg''}-\color{green}{f''g}-\color{red}{f'g'}+ \color{green}{f''g} =$$$$=f''g+f'g'+fg''$$

which is false in general, of course...

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is wrong. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule and try induction with the true formula.

Comment: I don't want to show the product rule.

Comment: OK. Now I see it. Apply your formula to $f$ and $g'$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
At first this question seems to be naive but it is not. Denote $u=f(x),v=g(x)$ then question can be simplified as follow
$$uv^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(u^{(k)}v)^{(n-k)}=uv^{(n)}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(u^{(k)}v)^{(n-k)}$$
or simply as
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(u^{(k)}v)^{(n-k)}=0$$
from Leibnitz rule we have that
$$(u^{(k)}v)^{(n-k)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{i}u^{(k+i)}v^{(n-(k+i))}$$
the real question is to prove that
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{i}u^{(k+i)}v^{(n-(k+i))}=0$$