# $f(x){d^ng(x)\over dx^n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}(_{k}^{n}){d^{n-k}\over dx^{n-k}}(f^{k}(x)g(x))$

Tags: derivatives

**Rule**

$f(x){d^ng(x)\over dx^n}= \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}(_{k}^{n}){d^{n-k}\over dx^{n-k}}(f^{k}(x)g(x))$

Above rule looks transformation of Leibniz's rule.

Tried to prove it but has a problem to transform the parameters of Combination.

Anyone can prove this rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that we seek to simplify

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k
\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{n-k} (f^{(k)}(x) g(x))$$

we obtain from Leibniz the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n-k\choose q} f^{(n-q)}(x) g^{(q)}(x)$$

or

$$\sum_{q=0}^n f^{(n-q)}(x) g^{(q)}(x)
\sum_{k=0}^{n-q} {n\choose k} (-1)^k {n-k\choose q}
\\ = f(x) g^{(n)}(x)
+ \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} f^{(n-q)}(x) g^{(q)}(x)
\sum_{k=0}^{n-q} {n\choose k} (-1)^k {n-k\choose q}.$$

With $q\lt n$ we introduce

$${n-k\choose q} = {n-k\choose n-k-q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n-k-q+1}} (1+z)^{n-k}
\; dz$$

The pole vanishes  when $k\gt n-q$ so  we may extend the  inner sum to
$k=n$ and get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n-q+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k \frac{z^k}{(1+z)^k}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n-q+1}} (1+z)^{n}
\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^n
\; dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n-q+1}}
\; dz.$$

Now with $q\lt  n$ we get $2\le  n-q+1\le n+1$ so this is  zero and we
have the claim.

**Remark.**  Looking at  the links  in the  sidebar we  see that  this
question      also      appeared      here      at      this      [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638273/). No  proof was
given however.